# Can I leave covered gaps between breakers in a panel?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

I am installing a 60 amp EV charger and have a some open slots in my electric panel for a  60 amp breaker. If I want to place the breaker at the bottom of the panel, is it ok to skip a few of the empty slots and place the breaker away from the others? Do breakers have to be installed consecutively in a panel?

Answer (score 3):

No, breakers do not have to be placed consecutively; given enough wire inside the panel box they can be arranged however makes the most sense for you. My solar connects to a breaker in the lower right corner, far from anything else.